# Constructor in component breaks connect react-redux in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, containers

I have the following example for a Typescript class. I have an error on the connect function from 'react-redux' (the last line of code) and I do not understand why. I need the constructor there for other things and it seems that because of it the error appears. Any ideas?

```
interface ITestClassProps extends IStateProps, IDispatchProps {}

interface IStateProps {
  isDisabled: boolean;
}

interface IDispatchProps {
  onClick: () => void;
}

class TestClass extends PureComponent<ITestClassProps, {}> {
  constructor(props: ITestClassProps) {
    super(props);

    ...
  }

  public render() {
    return (
      <div />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state: any): IStateProps => {
  return {
    isDisabled: state.isLoading
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any): IDispatchProps => ({
  onClick: actions.onClick
});

default connect<IStateProps, IDispatchProps, {}>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(TestClass);
```

Error:

```
[ts]
Argument of type 'typeof TestClass' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Component<IStateProps & IDispatchProps>'.
  Type 'typeof TestClass' is not assignable to type 'StatelessComponent<IStateProps & IDispatchProps>'.
    Type 'typeof TestClass' provides no match for the signature '(props: IStateProps & IDispatchProps & { children?: ReactNode; }, context?: any): ReactElement<any> | null'.
class TestClass
```

Comment: Can't reproduce with your code, I only get this error if `props` has a different type or `ITestClassProps` does not implement both interfaces (tested with latest definitions from npm)

Comment: I have "react-redux": "4.4.5" and "@types/react-redux": "4.4.47"

Comment: Still works, TS 2.7.2 & @types/react-redux@4.4.47

Comment: same here :( and it still happens

Answer (score 0):

so it seems that if I write `constructor(props?: ITestClassProps)` it works. I saw that in @types the signature for constructor has `props?` and maybe there is a conflict between them